# Typscript error when accessing object's value by string index

Tags: typescript

In javascript, accessing object value via `obj.field` can be done by `obj['field']` too. But produces error in typescript.

```
function F() {
  const obj = { field: "firstname", title: "First Name", value: 10 };
  let field = "field"
  console.log(obj[field]); // <-- Typescript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ field: string; title: string; value: number; }'
}
```

How can I cast `obj` to resolve typescript error?

Comment: It complains because the property key is evaluated at runtime. You can cast the key to assure typescript compiler it will be always one of those values`console.log(obj[field as keyof typeof obj] )`

Comment: @SvetoslavPetkov works well tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly annotate `field` as follows:

```
function F() {
  const obj = { field: 'firstname', title: 'First Name', value: 10 };
  const field: keyof typeof obj = 'field'; // field is narrowed to be a known key of obj instead of 'string'

  console.log(obj[field]); // no type error here
}
```

Comment: I think the term *narrow* is being used incorrectly here. That's actually just an explicit type annotation.

Comment: yes, in the technical typescript sense you are right. I thought of narrowing in a broader sense here. would you agree with 'explicitly narrow'?

Comment: Not really, I'd say narrowing is reducing a wider type to a more specific one with conditions in your code that are interpreted by the CFA.

Comment: edited answer to wording: 'explicitly annotate'

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're storing the `field` variable in a mutable variable (you're using `let` to assign). That means the type-engine can not assume that the type of `field` is `Literal<"field">`, but rather just `string`, of which `obj` doesn't have a typing.

To remedy the issue, either write `const field = "field"`, or add a manual typing to it, to limit the field variable's possible features:

```
function F() {
  const obj = { field: "firstname", title: "First Name", value: 10 };
  let field = "field" as "field" | "title" | "value"
  console.log(obj[field]); // <-- No error
}
```

<sub>[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMQBQEpEG8BQjEQIDOUicARgFaIC82iwMApgDYAmAXIgESMBOJMAEMAtk24AaRLCgsmXbshgDSAOVHipANyEsQ8xAEYADIgC+AbjyI5pRqza0e99t0RCiz5q8QAfHjJybv7cOnri1oRgRHByAHQscADmqBSUANoubAC66BaIAPQFiAA8ALRliKpwiEx8fHB8OGZAA)</sub>

---

If you don't want to re-write all the keys, you can do as @Hoopra says, and just use the `keyof typeof obj` syntax:

```
function F() {
  const obj = { field: "firstname", title: "First Name", value: 10 };
  let field = "field" as keyof typeof obj
  console.log(obj[field]); // <-- No error
}
```

<sub>[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMQBQEpEG8BQjEQIDOUicARgFaIC82iwMApgDYAmAXIgESMBOJMAEMAtk24AaRLCgsmXbshgDSAOVHipANyEsQ8xAEYADIgC+AbjyI5pRqza0e99t0RCiiANZMAnnGBpXwAHJgCyKmtCMCI4OQA6FjgAc1QKSgBtFzYAXXQLRAB6QsQAHgBacsRVOEQmPj44PhwzIA)</sub>

Comment: that's a snippet from a big set of different type of objects, so I can't write any literals. but your second recommendation works well. tnx

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is doing it job well and protecting you from accessing a property that may not exist anymore by the time of execution.

```
let field = "field"
```

TS is inferring the type to be string, and therefore you may be accessing something on `obj` that doesn't exist. The reason is because `let` declares a value, and someone could come and add a line to change the value of `field`. And so, the compiler has no assurance that the value remains `"field"`.

One way to fix this, and understand why TS does that, is to change `let field` to be `const field`. A constant doesn't change and so TS takes this into account and will allow you do to this.

If you need field to be dynamic, you could also do something like the following;

```
let field: 'field' | 'title' = "field"
```

This way the compiler knows that `obj[field]` has the type `string`, since both keys refer to a string value.

Comment: field is used in a lot of object types and can almost be considered dynamic (but I am sure it is one of the allowed values). that's why I am using `let` and I can't write any literals.

Comment: I undestand that typescript does its job well, but problem is I have little time to deliver first version of product, and cannot refactor that field among so many different object types :(